# Does Gmail honor icalendar replies (METHOD:REPLY)?

Tags: gmail, icalendar

Attendee is accepting a meeting created previously by organizer and received via email as ics file.

Here's a reply attendee is sending:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REPLY
PRODID:-//XXX//YYY//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:6i4roaen7444fh8n1imnq75ujt@google.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DTSTAMP:20190406T082440Z
DTSTART:20190406T180000Z
DTEND:20190406T190000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=organizer@gmail.com:MAILTO:organizer@gmail.com
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:qwerty
DESCRIPTION:-::~:[CUT]:~:~::-
LOCATION:
ATTENDEE;CN=organizer@gmail.com;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RS
 VP=TRUE:MAILTO:organizer@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN=attendee@gmail.com;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED
 ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:attendee@gmail.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

...and an email attendee is sending back to the organizer:

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; name="qwerty.ics"; method="REPLY"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Sat, 06 Apr 2019 10:34:40 +0200
Message-ID: <6dc076ea-6770-4e6a-bc62-a6c630d38f14@example.com>
From: <attendee@gmail.com>
To: <organizer@gmail.com>

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
[CUT]
END:VCALENDAR
```

Organizer simply gets the email in his inbox (ics is shown as attachment) but calendar event is not updated with the attendee status.

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is - duplicated ATTENDEE row.